# Which product sales is Increasing year wise?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table name is SALES

```
**PROD_ID**    **YEAR**    **QUANTITY**
  P1             2012         50
  P1             2013         40
  P1             2014         30
  P2             2012         20
  P2             2013         30
  P2             2014         40
```

Output should be P2 but how..?

Comment: Does it have to be increasing every year or only in the end result?

Comment: Only end result, Because If you check quantity of product P2 then its Increasing year wise, so that my Output should be P2

Answer (score 3):

This question can be approached with 2 steps

First, create a column to calculate difference of current year sales from previous year using lag function from windows, and then another column to calculate the distinct number of years for each PROD_ID

Second, Group the data using a group by clause on PROD_ID and filter the correct products only if all the distinct years had a positive sales compared to last year.

Data Table -

```
+---------+------+-------+
| PROD_ID | Year | Sales |
+---------+------+-------+
| P1      | 2012 |    50 |
| P1      | 2013 |    40 |
| P1      | 2014 |    30 |
| P2      | 2012 |    20 |
| P2      | 2013 |    30 |
| P2      | 2014 |    40 |
+---------+------+-------+
```

Query -

```
select PROD_ID 
from
    (
    select 
    PROD_ID, sales,
    sales - LAG(sales,1,0) over (partition by PROD_ID order by year asc) as diff,
    count(year) over (partition by PROD_ID) as num_of_years
    from sales
    ) inner_tbl
group by PROD_ID,num_of_years 
having SUM(CASE WHEN diff > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = num_of_years
```

Innner query output -

```
+---------+--------+------+--------------+
| PROD_ID |  sales | diff | num_of_years |
+---------+--------+------+--------------+
| P1      |     50 |   50 |            3 |
| P1      |     40 |  -10 |            3 |
| P1      |     30 |  -10 |            3 |
| P2      |     20 |   20 |            3 |
| P2      |     30 |   10 |            3 |
| P2      |     40 |   10 |            3 |
+---------+--------+------+--------------+
```

Final output -

```
+---------+
| PROD_ID |
+---------+
| P2      |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
select prod_id
from sales
group by prod_id
having (sum(case when year = 2014 then quantity else 0 end) >
        sum(case when year = 2012 then quantity else 0 end)
       );
```

Comment: My Output Should be P2 only, Because Product P2 sale is increasing, If you check my table data

Comment: Based on your data it appears you would always be comparing 2012 data against 2014 data. Gordon's answer does that and would also exclude P1 from the output. I think that we don't know what you're really looking for.

Comment: @shawnt00..`increasing year wise` the question says..so i assume there should be an increase for each year

Comment: @vkp I'm inclined to agree but you did see the comment that only "end result" matters?

Comment: yeah..i guess the op doesn't exactly know what he needs or maybe he is phrasing it wrong

Answer (score 2):

A slightly complex way to accomplish this with `cte`s.

[**Fiddle with sample data**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17848/22)

```
with diff as ( 
select prod_id ,
case when quantity - nvl(lag(quantity) over(partition by prod_id order by yr),0) > 0 
then 1 else 0 end as df
from sales 
)
,totdiff as (select prod_id, sum(df) totdf from diff group by prod_id)
, totals as (select prod_id, count(*)  cnt from sales group by prod_id)
select d.prod_id
from totdiff d join totals t on t.prod_id = d.prod_id and d.totdf = t.cnt
```

Edit: as suggested by @shawnt00 in the comments..the query could be simplified to

```
with diff as ( 
select prod_id ,
case when quantity - nvl(lag(quantity) over(partition by prod_id order by yr),0) > 0 
then 1 else 0 end as df
from sales 
)
select prod_id 
from diff 
group by prod_id
having count(*) = sum(df)
```

Comment: Is it clearer to just say `from diff group by prod_id having sum(df) = count(*)`? I'm wondering if you had a reason to do it that way with the join.

Comment: yeah..it would be the same and infact a few lines of code lesser..but i prefer to write it this way for a better understanding..included your suggestion too..@shawnt00

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old question, posting answer since i was able to solve it in a different way.

```
create table sales (prod_id varchar(10), yr int, quantity int);

insert into sales values ('P1',2012 , 50);
insert into sales values ('P1', 2013, 40);
insert into sales values ('P1', 2014, 30);
insert into sales values ('P2', 2012, 20);
insert into sales values ('P2', 2013, 30);
insert into sales values ('P2', 2014, 40);

with next_year_sales as 
(
select s.prod_id, s.yr, nvl(s1.yr,0) as prev_yr, s.quantity, nvl(s1.quantity,0) as prev_qty from sales s 
left outer join sales s1 on s.prod_id = s1.prod_id and s.yr = s1.yr+1 
),
flag_high_sales as
(
select prod_id, yr, case when prev_yr=0 then 1 when quantity > prev_qty then 1 else 0 end as flag from next_year_sales A
)

select prod_id, min(flag) from flag_high_sales group by prod_id having min(flag)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways of doing it :

```
select a.prod_id from
(
select
prod_id,
CASE WHEN quantity > coalesce(lag(quantity) over(partition by prod_id order by year asc),0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as val
FROM
sales
) a
group by a.prod_id
having sum(a.val) = count(prod_id)
;
```

```
select a.prod_id from
(
select
prod_id,
quantity - coalesce(lag(quantity) over(partition by prod_id order by year asc),0) as val
FROM
sales
) a
group by a.prod_id
having min(a.val) >=0
;
```

```
select a.prod_id from
(
select
prod_id,
year - dense_rank() over(partition by prod_id order by quantity asc) as cal
FROM
sales
) a
group by a.prod_id
having count(distinct cal)=1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses CTE and OVER CLAUSE -

```
WITH Sales_CTE
AS (
    SELECT n1.Prod_ID AS n1Prod_ID
        ,COUNT(n1.Year) OVER (PARTITION BY n1.Prod_ID) AS #CountYn1
        ,COUNT(n2.Year) OVER (PARTITION BY n1.Prod_ID) AS #CountYn2
    FROM #Q2 n1
    LEFT JOIN #Q2 n2 ON n1.Prod_ID = n2.Prod_ID
        AND (n1.Year + 1) = n2.Year
        AND n1.Quantity < n2.Quantity
    )
SELECT DISTINCT n1Prod_ID AS [Product ID]
FROM Sales_CTE
WHERE #CountYn1 = (#CountYn2 + 1);
```